# How do I catch the tabpanel navigation button click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I work with MS vs 2015 and C#

I have a tabpanel with multiple tabs

I want that the buttons that are used to navigate in the panels to be faster.

For that I have to intercept their click event but I cant find it in the properties

the navigation buttons are managed by windows so they show or hide depending on the amount of tabs. by default the are not shown in design mode if you fill your tab later programatically

What I have tried:

Looking at the properties windows of the tabpanel control

Comment: Share your code please, so that other people could help you.

Comment: Trying to make that go faster probably isn't going to work, and it's probably going about the problem in the wrong direction.  If you are going to have that many tabs open, you should probably provide a drop down list so the user can easily find the tab they are looking for from that.

Comment: There is no code to share  I am just trying to find the click event but is not listed.